# What level of complexity requires a framework?

Tags: frameworks, complexity-theory

At what level of complexity is it mandatory to switch to an existing framework for web development?

What measurement of complexity is practical for web development?  Code length?  Feature list?  Database Size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work on several different sites then by using a common framework across all of them you can spend time working on the code rather than trying to remember what is located where and why.

I'd always use a framework of some sort, even if it's your own, as the uniformity will help you structure your project. Unless it's a one page static HTML project.

There is no mandatory limit however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a level of complexity that necessitates a framework.  For me whenever I am writing a dynamic site I immediately consider a framework, and if it will save me time, I use it(it almost always does, and I almost always do).

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the question may be faulty. Many of the most complex websites don't use any popular, preexisting, framework. Google has their own web server and their own custom way of doing things, as does Amazon, and probably lots of other sites.

If a framework makes your task easier, or provides added value, go for it. However, when you get that framework you are tied to a new dependancy. I'm starting to essentially recreate a Joel on Software post, so I will redirect you here for more on adding unneeded dependencies to your code:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html

Answer (score 0):

All factors matter. You should measure how much time you can save using 3rd party framework and compare it to the risks of using other's code

Comment: I think you meant 'compare' rather than 'confront' there.

Answer (score 0):

Never "mandatory." Some problems are not well solved by any framework. It would be suggestible to switch to a framework when most of the code you are implementing has already be implemented by the framework in question in a way that suits your particular application. This saves you time, energy, and will most likely be more stable than the fresh code you would have written.

Answer (score 0):

This is really two questions, you realize. :-)  The answer to the first one is that it's never *mandatory*, but honestly, parsing HTML request parameters directly is pretty horrible right from the start.  I don't want to do it even once, so I tend to go toward a framework relatively early on.

As far as what measurement is practical, well, what are you worried about?  All of the descriptions that you list have value.  Database size matters primarily for scaling, in my opinion (you can write a very simple app if you have a very simple schema, even if there are hundreds of thousands of rows in the database).  The feature list will probably determine the number and complexity of UI pages, which will in turn help to dictate the code length.

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks that are there for getting moving very quickly with a simple blog, [django](http://www.djangoproject.com) or [RoR](http://www.rubyonrails.org) all the way to enterprise full-stack applications [Zope](http://www.zope.org). Not to be tied to just the buzz world, you also have ASP.Net and J2EE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All frameworks and libraries are tools at your disposal. Determine which ones will make your life easier for your given project and use them.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the reverse is true.  At some point, your project gets so expansive, that you actually get slowed down by the shortcomings of the framework.  For sufficiently large projects you may, in fact, be better off developing your own framework, to meet your own needs.  I have seen many times where people were held back in the decisions they could make, or the work they could produce, because they were trying to do something that the framework didn't anticipate.  And doing these things that the framework doesn't anticipate can be very troublesome.  The nice thing about making your own framework, is that it can evolve with your project, to be a help to you system, instead of a hindrance.

So, to conclude, small projects should be use existing frameworks.  Large projects should contain their own framework.